# Automatizing controlling of Skype Linux UI application

Tags: qt, x11, skype, user-interaction, xvfb

I am the author of project Sevabot http://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/ - a Skype bot for Linux.

As the server installation is painful ( https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ubuntu.html ) I'd like to figure out how to make it simpler for the users to use the bot throught cloud deployments... to the point we can ask Skype username, password and some cloud service credentials and automatically deploy the bot to the customers on the virtual machine provider like Amazon EC2. We'd like to make the deployment possible in a such way that one doesn't need to run VNC just to connect your Xvfb to enter the Skype login on the first time.

One challenge is automatizing Skype Linux UI input (username, password). Skype does not seem to be an option to enter user credentials in automatized way from the command line. As far as I know the user interface is Qt based and you need some sort of robot to choose widgets and simulate keypresses and mouse.

I'd like to know what options there exist for controlling blackbox Linux UI applications and automatize actions for them?